# Transposed convolution in tf.keras.layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras

How can I convert this function to an equivalent tf.keras (Tensorflow 2.0) implementation?

```
def deconv2d(inputs,out_channels, name=None):
batch, in_height, in_width, in_channels = [int(d) for d in inputs.get_shape()]
filter = tf.get_variable(name + "filter", [4, 4, out_channels, in_channels], initializer= tf.variance_scaling_initializer())
return tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(inputs, filter, [batch, in_height * 2, in_width * 2, out_channels], strides=[1,2,2,1],
                             padding='SAME', name= name)
```

Answer (score 1):

TensoFlow 2.0 has `tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose`. Keras is the default high level API for TF 2.0, but it still have `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose` for low level applications

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2DTranspose

Comment: Hi, Yes, I knew that.My question is perhaps for directed at Line 3 `tf.get_variable()`.  I understand Keras has its own way of managing shared variables. I'm just not sure if that would work.

Comment: You can use `tf.Variable` instead, see https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/migration_guide